# How to store Global Javascript Variables in asp.net app

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm trying to use a global variable in JavaScript in an asp.net app.

I have a button that registers a script:

```
     Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(),"showModel",String.Format("<script>showModel('{0}', '{1}');</script>", objID, token))
```

That script has a global variable defined. But when I use the same method to call another function on the script, the global variable is null.
Is there another call to use the script after t has been registered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to call the script registered in your code, you will need to define your script as a function to be referenced elsewhere after the script loads:

```
function dosomething(){
   showModel('{0}', '{1}')
}

//Later in your script:
dosomething()
```

Otherwise the second argument (`"showModel"`) in your code is the name given to the registered script. By global variable what exactly are you referring to?